# How can I encode my special character, so that it is compartible to use it as a link?

Tags: php, special-characters, href

I have a string with a special character:

```
$elephant = "Ele╠phant";
```

Then I am encoding the string:

```
$elephant_encoded = htmlspecialchars(urlencode($elephant));
```

The result is: `Ele%E2%95%A0phant`

But now I want to use it in a link:

```
echo "<a href='".$elephant_encoded."'>".$elephant."</a>";
```

The html looks also ok:

```
<a href="Ele%E2%95%A0phant">Ele╠phant</a>
```

But when I click on the link it magically changes the link and goes to the adress `Ele╠phant`.

But I need an adress without special characters!

How can I solve this. Is there another encoding possibility?

Comment: You could use Base64 to encode your string. It just needs a little adjustment for some of the special characters in a B64 encoding. You can grab this function for a URL friendly B64 encode/decode: https://gist.github.com/Stickano/2078481469f6abc3d8307b40198aceec

Comment: Thank you! The result is "RWxl4pWgcGhhbnQ"

Comment: @Jeppesen There is a problem with this encoding. For some words it uses points `...` This is not so good in a link

Comment: You can replace that character if you like. This line; `$base = strtr($string,  '-_.', '+/=');` replaces B64 special characters to different character. So here the `=` would be replaced with a . (dot). Just replace the . (dot) in ` '-_.'` to whatever you'd like it replaced with. Remember to do so in both encode and decode^

Comment: @Jeppesen Ok! I will check it out!

Comment: Does it work? If yes, then stop worrying about how it looks like in the browser's address bar.

Comment: @axiac Yes it is working! Thank you!